# terraform azuread_user returns "Error: User not found with object ID .."

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

I am using terraform data source azuread_user to retrieve all members of an Azure AD group:

```
data "azuread_group" "group" {
  display-name = "group_display_name"
  security_enabled = true
}

data "azuread_user" "members"
  for_each = to_set(data.azuread_group.group.members)
  object_id = each.key
}
```

this works fine, as long as there are only users as members of that group. Now I've added service principal to that group, and understandably terraform cannot find a user with object ID of a service principal:

```
Error: User not found with object ID "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddddddddddd"
```

Later I assign all the members of that group as owners to other AAD groups. What would be the best way to keep the service principal in that group and filter out only users with data source azuread_user (if possible)? Maybe I'll need to rethink the whole concept of user-permission assignment because of this ..

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with following code:

```
data "azuread_group" "group" {  
  display_name = "DemoGroup"
  security_enabled = true
}


data "azuread_user" "members"{
   for_each = toset(data.azuread_group.group.members)
   object_id = each.key
 }
```

Got error:

```
│ Error: User not found with object ID: "bxx"
│
│   with data.azuread_user.members["bxxxxc"],
│   on main.tf line 185, in data "azuread_user" "members":
│  185:   object_id = each.key
│
```

[image]

The azuread_user data source cannot retrieve service principal objects.
Instead  output of the user values  get all members irrespective of whether it is service principal or not.
[image]

code:

```
data "azuread_group" "group" {
  display_name = "DemoGroup"
  security_enabled = true
}


output "grpmem" {
  value = data.azuread_group.group.members
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
grpmem = tolist([
  "6587fxxxe30",
  "92xxx06b0",
  "bb4xxx11cc",
])
```

[image]